# Share Dynamic Data on Facebook

Tags: php, html, facebook

```
$title = "BITCHES LOVE BALLET";
$title.= ' Sign up for my guestlist,bottle service or tickets straight from your phone using PromoterX app:';
$url='http://onelink.to/yhthk6';

<a class="btn btn-circle btn-icon-only btn-primary" target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=<?= $url?>&title=<?= $title ?>">share on facebook</a>
```

i am not able to set title in Facebook when i share this on Facebook. and second thing Facebook retrieves title from the link i set in url.please help me to get out of it.your help would be highly appreciated.thank in advance.

Comment: add og:title to the link which you want to post

Comment: @HasiburRahaman  it's not working yet,

Answer (score 0):

```
    i got the solution and it's working but when posting on facebook it doesn't take title and description.
<?php      
          $title  = "BITCHES LOVE BALLET";
          $summary = 'Sign up for my guestlist,bottle service or tickets straight from your phone using PromoterX app';                                                      
    ?>            
        <a  target="_blank" href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://onelink.to/yhthk6&title=<?=$title;?>&description=<?=$summary;?>">share on facebook</a>
```